# How to track users across domains?

Tags: php, tracking, ads

We got pitched this idea yesterday. A user visits our site and are marked. Then when they visit other sites like CNN they are targeted with adds for our site. So once they are exposed to us, they start to see us everywhere, creating the illusion we are bigger than we are.

The person pitching it said it was done by cookies. I was very skeptical since I don't believe there to be anyway to see what cookies a different domain has set. So I wanted to try an figure out how it was accomplished. The salesman called this technology *pixel tracking*.

I have never heard of pixel tracking but from my research I have found that it is placing a 1 pixel image that references a script on another domain with parameters to be executed. My first thought was, OK maybe its possible this way.. But I still don't know how?

Can anyone explain how they are able to mark you as visited our site, and then see this mark on another site? Is it from your IP?

Comment: Don't trust salespeople.

Comment: @driis, I don't :) ..Thats why I am doing my research (That and an opportunity to learn something interesting.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Included at the bottom of the (CNN) website in this case is an img tag like:

```
<img src="http://www.webmarketingCompany.com/pixel.php?ID=623489593479">
```

When a user visits the (CNN) website, and the browser renders the page, it sends http requests for all the images as well, including a request to http://www.webmarketingCompany.com for the image pixel.php which includes the ID as a get parameter. pixel.php not only returns an image, typically a 1x1 transparent gif (so it isn't visible in the rendered page), but can do a whole host of additional processing using the ID value; and it also has access to any webmarketingCompany.com cookies, which are also sent with the http request.

Of course, CNN have to agree to include the img tag in their html. Typically it's used as a tracker by third party marketing companies working on behalf of CNN to identify who is visiting their site, what pages they're viewing, etc.

But because it's a PHP script, it can do a whole host of extras, such as setting further cookies. If webmarketingCompany.com also handle ad-serving on behalf of CNN, they can do some creative selection of the ads that they choose to serve.

Such cross-client "pollination" is frowned upon, certainly here in the UK.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize CNN's cookies would be sent in that request.

Comment: Did I say CNN cookies? I meant webmarketingCompany.com cookies.

Comment: CNN.com's cookies aren't sent, but when the user visits CNN.com and loads the advert, the cookie set by the advertising company lets them know who the user is to look up in the database where they've been recently.

Comment: Gotcha, I was still a little confused but I think I get it now. They visit my site and set a cookie on webmarketingCompany.com then visit cnn.com and it checks for the same webmarketingCompany.com cookie.

Comment: That about sums it up. As long as webmarketingCompany.com is doing adserving or tracking or whatever for CNN, then they'll be able to send their identifying cookies back to their servers whenever you access CNN. If webmarketingCompany.com does its work on a lot of busy sites, then they can track a lot of user activity... needs to be a company with the significant, big contracts though: they can't track you (legally) on sites where they don't have a contract... but if they're a big player in the tracking/analytics marketplace (Google or Microsoft for example) then they do have the resources.

Comment: I hasten to add that while I work in the tracking/analytics marketplace, my company does not cross-reference between clients in this way. Even if a user visits several of our client company websites, we treat the client/user reference as unique and neither log nor promote inter-client activity or analytics.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is pretty standard for all advertisement networks. The only difference here is that they will place that cookie on your site as well.

As long as the browser has "accept third party cookies" set to true, this will work as the salesman said. Most browsers has the setting set to true by default, the only exception I can think of is Safari.